# imagens mostrar descrição quando passa o mouse em um div separado

Tags: javascript, html

Quero colocar uma imagem do lado da outra e quando passa o mouse em cima aparece uma descrição em uma coluna separada do site, caso nao tenha jeito pode ser na mesma desde que de para colocar uma imagem do lado da outra e as descrições nao desfigurem as imagens ao lado quando der o :hover

se não der em html podem me ajudar no javascript... CSS q to usando:

```
.descricao, descricaodois{
    display: none;
}
.item:hover .descricao, .itemdois:hover .descricaodois{
    display: block;
}
```

html:

```
<span class="item"><a href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8sBmNaN.jpg"/></a>
    <span class="descricao">Recomendado a todas as idades</span>
</span>
<span class="itemdois"><a href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/x4REsTX.jpg"/></a>
    <span class="descricaodois">Hoje o dia pode ser seu</span>
</span>
```

quando passa o mouse a descrição afeta a imagem do lado por isso queria deixar em uma div ou span diferente  separado da imagem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Você pode fazer com javascript diretamente no elemento ou separado**

*As descrições estão em uma `div` separada*

- No elemento:

```css
.descricao, .descricaodois{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="item" onmouseover="document.getElementById('des1').style.display='block'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('des1').style.display='none'"><a href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8sBmNaN.jpg"/></a>
</span>
<span class="itemdois"  onmouseover="document.getElementById('des2').style.display='block'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('des2').style.display='none'"><a href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/x4REsTX.jpg"/></a>
</span>
<div id="descricoes">
<span class="descricao" id="des1">Recomendado a todas as idades</span>
<span class="descricaodois" id="des2">Hoje o dia pode ser seu</span>
</div>
```

- Script separado:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("item")[0].onmouseover = function(){document.getElementsByClassName("descricao")[0].style.display="block";}
document.getElementsByClassName("item")[0].onmouseout = function(){document.getElementsByClassName("descricao")[0].style.display="none";}
document.getElementsByClassName("itemdois")[0].onmouseover = function(){document.getElementsByClassName("descricaodois")[0].style.display="block";}
document.getElementsByClassName("itemdois")[0].onmouseout = function(){document.getElementsByClassName("descricaodois")[0].style.display="none";}
```

```css
.descricao, .descricaodois{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="item" onmouseover="document.getElementById('des1').style.display='block'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('des1').style.display='none'"><a href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/8sBmNaN.jpg"/></a>
</span>
<span class="itemdois"  onmouseover="document.getElementById('des2').style.display='block'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('des2').style.display='none'"><a href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/x4REsTX.jpg"/></a>
</span>
<div id="descricoes">
<span class="descricao">Recomendado a todas as idades</span>
<span class="descricaodois">Hoje o dia pode ser seu</span>
</div>
```